# CSS: Is it possible to put shadow onto the outline of a background-less PNG image?

Tags: css, shadow

Now these days I want to believe **everything is possible**, when I saw the power of CSS - making irregular shapes with block elements, i.e. [triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work), [chamfered CSS Border Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770312/how-to-achieve-chamfered-css-border-corners-rather-than-rounded-corners) — how easy but how enthusiastic! So I tried to dream about something, something that I believe can be possible with some great knowledge of CSS.

```
div.image{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url(images/image-sprite.png) -70px 0;
    display: inline-block;
   }
```

Suppose I put an "Image Sprite" ([image: image-sprite.png]) with a width and height of 18px. But the image I called is NOT an 18px x 18px box-shaped image, suppose the image is Round or some Irregular shapes. When I put `box-shadow` to the div, it highlighted like a box, when I put `text-shadow`, it doesn't work, as the div/anchor element doesn't contain any texts in it.

[image: image-sprite.png]

If I want to put shadow onto the element, not onto the container (like a box-shaped HTML element), as the image shown, shadow to the outline of the background-less image only — then:

- How can it be done with CSS? or,
- Is that really possible?

**NOTE:** I know, when I have a background-less image and Photoshop, I can put necessary shadows into almost any element. But I asked the question, **if** something like this can be possible with raw CSS then it'd be a great achievement for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new CSS filters will allow you to do this but browser support is not super deep.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvuqp)

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.equissage.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/equissage-red-horse.png" alt="" />
</div>

.image img {
  width:400px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px grey);

}
```

Comment: It's an excellent solution - though Webkit only, but good that something exists at least.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you're asking is by recreating the shape with css or using a icon font.

As the element you want to border-shadow is an image these always become square or rectangular.